# MSVC 2008: Cannot View Reigsters or Memory with Native Code

Tags: visual-c++, debugging

I am having trouble viewing the registers and memory in Visual Studio 2008. I am working with native code with no CLR. I have tried the following:

```
>Debug.Registers
Command "Debug.Registers" is not available.
Ctrl+Alt G
>Debug.Memory1
Command "Debug.Memory1" is not available.
Ctrl+Alt+M 1
The key command (Ctrl+Alt+M, 1) is currently bound to (Memory &1) which is currently not available.
```

However, this will work:

```
>Debug.ListRegisters
EAX = 0023FC98 EBX = 7FFDF000 ECX = 00000000 EDX = 000E21A8 ESI = 00000000 
EDI = 0023FCC4 EIP = 0113D6C8 ESP = 0023FBA4 EBP = 0023FCC4 EFL = 00000202 
0023FC80 = 00000009 
>Debug.ListMemory
0x0113D6C8  8b 45 bc 50 8b 4d c8 51 68 a6 b9 13 01 8b 55 b0  .E.P.MÈQh¦....U°
```

I would like more control over the memory locations. I would like to change my locations rather than just have them listed in the command window.

In VS2005 I was able to have a to go to View->Other Windows->Registers. Is this feature not available in VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs across this question and has a similar problem it turned out that my default settings were for Visual Basic. Even though I was developing in native C++, most of the native debugging tools were unavailable. Once my default settings were reverted back to C/C++ everything worked as expected. Not only were the register and memory settings unavailable they were not present within the debugger toolbar.

[To reset your settings go to Tools->Export Import Settings and navigate to reset.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)

Comment: Actually, what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I was trying to utilize the native debugger tools, specifically the memory and register windows. These windows were unavailable to me because my default setup was for Visual Basic. Not only were the options hidden, even when I tried to use built in short-cuts with VC6 short-cuts enabled, I still could not access the native tools.